# Java CUP resources, is it still used?

Tags: java, parsing, documentation, resources, lalr

I have recently been tasked to working on code that uses Java CUP. Does anybody still use it? I've found a couple small resources on it, but it looks like there isn't much documentation on the main site, [Java Cup Website](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/CUP/). If there are any mailing-lists or users out there I would like to know. BTW, I can't use the new engine that is being maintained by the people in Munich, I got to stick with version 0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the newer one on the Eclipse XPath2 engine (disturbingly called PsychoPath).
CUP gets the job done, but we use the newer one.
Being a small piece of software, it's easier to understand, which makes up for the scarceness of resources.

Comment: I guess this didn't really answer your question, but at least feel free to ask...